# CSS Issue with SVG Icons in Mobile Menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress, svg

We have a weird issue with our SVG icons in our mobile menu. They appear very big in the mobile version although they are set at 1.6em.

Go [here](https://www.safe-company.com/), open the hamburger menu and click on the "Shop Now" Dropdown, you will see the size of the icons

We tried the following CSS in the WordPress Customizer but it seems like it's not that class, and that's weird because using the Chrome Developer Tools if we modify that class it seems to change.

```
.sidr-class-icon sidr-class-before sidr-class-svg {
max-width: 15%;
}
```

Note: Using !important tag also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class of this image is `class='sidr-class-icon sidr-class-before sidr-class-svg'`. So to select it in css you need to use:

```css
.sidr-class-icon.sidr-class-before.sidr-class-svg { ... }
```

And not:

```css
.sidr-class-icon sidr-class-before sidr-class-svg { ... }
```

```css
.sidr-class-icon.sidr-class-before.sidr-class-svg { 
    max-width: 15%;
    border: solid red 3px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.safe-company.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/bmeeting.svg" class="sidr-class-icon sidr-class-before sidr-class-svg" aria-hidden="true">
```

Comment: Yes I thought about this and then tried it, but it still doesn't work this way

Comment: @phriquez So you have another error to take into consideration but the selector work as you can see in the snippet ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help! It seems the issue is from other place... Have a nice day!

Comment: @phriquez No problem please don't forget to also `validate` my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting height and width attributes for your img tags.

Comment: It is actually what he asks for ;)